# How To Set Default Large Icon (Not default Icon) For Firebase FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I found many solutions how to set FCM default icon

I get these replies

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification_small" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

It helped me a lot.

But now I have another question that I never found solution for that, **How to set 
Default Large Icon for FCM?**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this only can be achieved programmatically, and by that way you can control more options related to notification.
In you class which `extends FirebaseMessagingService`
create `@Override` `onMessageReceived` 
handle the data and create the custom notification you want `NotificationCompat.InboxStyle` in `onMessageReceived` method.

Create a Firebase service in your `manifest` that if your app was close it will call `onMessageReceived` in the class that `extends FirebaseMessagingService`

```
<service
     android:name=".you_class_path_which_extends_FirebaseMessagingService"
     android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Comment: Maybe You are rite, But the problem is that when app is closed then even if I used my own class in the code, my code will not run. It'll run by own its own on operating system level. Android Play Service Handle this by its own :(